# htaccess 301 redirect domain/folder to new sub.domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I keep looking but can't find how to do this redirect.
the old URL is

```
http://nilandsplace.com/LinuxBlog/
```

I want to move it to:

```
http://blog.nilandsplace.com/linux/index.php
```

all the redirects I try are giving me a 500 server error or a 401 page not found with this URL/

```
http://blog.nilandsplace.com/linuxLinuxBlog/
```

I created a folder in the root directory /LinuxBlog/ that i put my .htaccess in. I can't seem to get rid of the /LinuxBlog

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

# if you want to redirect everything to index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nilandsplace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^LinuxBlog/ http://blog.nilandsplace.com/linux/index.php [R=301]

# if you want to keep the page requested and forward it to the new URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nilandsplace\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^LinuxBlog/(.*)$ http://blog.nilandsplace.com/linux/$1 [R=301]
```